# Get position of ViewPager after rotating in Android

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager. My FragmentPageAdapter returns the position of the Viewpager in the getItem() methode. But after rotating the Screen the methode returns no value. Why? If I understood it right, everytime you rotate the screen OnCreateView() is called, but why doesn't it return the value any more? Could someone point out how to solve this? Thank you

Edit: My FragmentPageAdapter:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

   return Fragment_results.newInstance(position);
}
```

My Fragment:

```
public static Fragment_results newInstance(int i) {

    Fragment_results fragment = new Fragment_results();
    fragment.mContent = i +"";

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_result, null);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(mContent);
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not returning a value?  The `getItem()` method is part of your PagerAdapter.  Whether or not it returns a value is completely dependent on your implementation.  `ViewPager#getCurrentItem()` will return the numbered position of the `ViewPager` which may be reset to `0` upon screen rotation.

Comment: I edited the question and included my code. But why get it reset to 0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The position is set to 0 upon creating of the ViewPager instance and whenever you set a new adapter.  When `onCreateView()` is called, you're rebuilding the entire app essentially.  In order to revert back to the position it was, you must first use `onSavedInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and store the item position via the Bundle.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  outState.putInt("pageItem", myViewPager.getCurrentItem());
}
```

Then in `onCreate`, restore the viewPager's state like so:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  myViewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("pageItem", 0));
}
```